# Qt - How to connect the comboBox to the database

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

I'm attempting to query the database and put the result in a combobox.

- db was initally declared public, but `lastError()` returned ***"driver not loaded"*** in the `openConnection()` function which checked `if(!db.open())`. The function returned true for win7, but false for win8 and XP.
- Not sure why this happened. Some forum comments suggest "declaring variable in header as a global leaves it up to the compiler when the object is created....db object is instantiated at the wrong time".
- the connection call from mainwindow was `QsqlDatabase db = dbConnector::getInstance()->db;`
- then db is used in the line for the combobox: `QSqlQuery* qry=new QSqlQuery(db);`

Instead of declaring db public:

- I created `comboBoxInit()`, because I don't think db can be accessed by mainwindow. (db is declared private)
- The current code returns "***ui is not declared in this scope***"

**How do you connect the comboBox to the db in this example?**

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "dbConnector.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    dbConnector *dbc = dbConnector::getInstance();

    if(!dbc->openConnection()) {
        ui->statusBar->showMessage("Failed to open the database");
    } else {
        ui->statusBar->showMessage("Connected");
    }

    dbConnector::getInstance()->comboBoxInit();

    //QSqlQueryModel * modal=new QSqlQueryModel();
    //QSqlQuery* qry=new QSqlQuery(db);
    //qry->prepare("select name from table");
    //qry->exec();

    modal->setQuery(*qry);
    ui->comboBox->setModel(modal);
    ui->comboBox_2->setModel(modal);

}
```

**dbConnector.h**

```
class dbConnector
{
    private:
      static dbConnector * _instance;
      dbConnector();
      QSqlDatabase db;

    public:
      static dbConnector * getInstance();

      bool openConnection();
      bool closeConnection();
      bool comboBoxInit();
      ~dbConnector();
};
```

**dbConnector.cpp**

```
dbConnector::dbConnector()
{
   if (!QSqlDatabase::isDriverAvailable(driver))
   {
       //QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("error::"),qry.lastError().text());
       QMessageBox::critical(0,connectError,driverExist);
       exit(1);
   }
   db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(driver);
   db.setDatabaseName(fileName);
   openConnection();
}

bool dbManager::comboBoxInit()
{
    QSqlQueryModel * modal=new QSqlQueryModel();
    QSqlQuery* qry=new QSqlQuery(db);
    qry->prepare("select name from table");
    qry->exec();

    modal->setQuery(*qry);
    //qDebug() << modal;

    return true;
    ui->comboBox->setModel(modal);
    ui->comboBox_2->setModel(modal);
}
```

Comment: No, C++ accessibility has no relation to "driver connection problems". There is no magic. The last magic was used up thousands of years ago.

Comment: Also, "ui is not declared in this scope" doesn't sound like "inaccessible".

Comment: "driver not loaded" - This means the database driver could not be loaded, which is a clear sign that a) a Qt driver plugin is missing or b) the native driver library could not be loaded or c) both. ;) Also make sure that the native library is the same bitness as the created executable.

Comment: @maxik : Any idea why a driver would load in win7, but not in win8 or XP?

Comment: @rrrfusco You have to differentiate between some more things here: is the Win7 your development machine with Qt installed? If not, then this is a clear sign that the native driver is not found or not the proper architecture type, namely 32 or 64 bit. You may try to set **QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS** variable for more information. Or query `QStringList QSqlDatabase::drivers()`.

Comment: @maxik I'm revising this question to be about c++. I opened a new question about drivers. Win7 is the development machine (64 bit). Output of qt debug is in the new question.